# How to receive any type of message in Akka.Net Receive Actor

Tags: c#, akka.net

I'm trying to implement a some sort of console writer for all of my actors.
Here's my code:

```
class ConsoleWriterActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public ConsoleWriterActor()
    {
        Receive<object>(s =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is, somehow the actor doesnt receive any messages. I got this log from console:

```
[INFO][8/5/2015 7:30:06 AM][Thread 0013 [akka://SPBOActorSystem/user/ConsoleWriterActor] Message StartDbOperator from akka://SPBOActorSystem/user/DbOperatorActor to akka://SPBOActorSystem/user/ConsoleWriterActor was not delivered. 1 dead letters encountered.
```

What went wrong ?

Comment: I apologize. The console actor was instantiated with different props.

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like you sorted out the `DeadLetters` question. To answer your original question: To receive any message in a `ReceiveActor`, use `ReceiveAny`([docs](http://getakka.net/docs/ReceiveActor#receiveany)), like so:

```
class ConsoleWriterActor : ReceiveActor
{
    public ConsoleWriterActor()
    {
        ReceiveAny(o => Console.WriteLine("Received object: " + o));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Didnt know ReceiveAny() existed.